# Not able to get mutex locks to prevent threads from accessing a function

Tags: c, mutex, semaphore, consumer, producer

Working on the Producer and Consumer problem for a class and having trouble just putting on the final touches. The problem I am encountering is that i think my mutex locks are not locking my threads out of the function. For example if I run the program and pass it the parameters 2 4 4 7 it would print 8 7's and then 2 seconds later it will print 8 8's and then 8 9's and so on. I have tried using trylock and moving around the semaphores but to no avail. Is there something that I am missing when that is causing none of the threads to be locked out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
typedef int buffer_item;
#define BUFFER_SIZE 5
#define TRUE 1


buffer_item START_NUMBER;
int counter;
int insert_item(buffer_item item);
int remove_item(buffer_item *item);  
buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
void* producer(void *ptr);
void* consumer(void *ptr);  
pthread_cond_t condc, condp;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int sleepTime, producerThreads, consumerThreads,a;
pthread_attr_t attr;
sem_t full, empty;

int insert_item(buffer_item item)
{
   if(counter < BUFFER_SIZE) {
      buffer[counter] = item;
      counter++;
      return 0;
   }
   else { 
      return -1;
   }
}
int remove_item(buffer_item *item)
{
   if(counter > 0) {
      *item = buffer[(counter-1)];
      counter--;
      return 0;
   }
   else { 
      return -1;
   }
}

void* producer(void *ptr) {
     buffer_item item;
     item = START_NUMBER;
   while(TRUE) {
      sleep(sleepTime);     
      sem_wait(&empty);
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);    
      if(insert_item(item)) {
         fprintf(stderr, "error \n");
      }
      else {
         printf("producer%u produced %d\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self(),item);
         item++;
      }     
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      sem_post(&full);
   }
        }
void* consumer(void *ptr) {
   buffer_item item;
   while(TRUE) {
      sleep(sleepTime);
      sem_wait(&full);
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      if(remove_item(&item)) {
         fprintf(stderr, "error \n");
      }
      else {
         printf("consumer%u consumed %d\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self(),item);
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      sem_post(&empty);

   }
}
void initializeData() {
   pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
   sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&empty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
   pthread_attr_init(&attr);
   counter = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    sleepTime = atoi(argv[1]);
    producerThreads = atoi(argv[2]);
    consumerThreads = atoi(argv[3]);
    START_NUMBER = atoi(argv[4]);
    initializeData();
    pthread_t pro, con;


    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&condc, NULL); 
    pthread_cond_init(&condp, NULL); 

   for(a=0; a< consumerThreads;a++)
    pthread_create(&con, NULL, consumer, NULL);
    for(a=0;a<producerThreads;a++)
    pthread_create(&pro, NULL, producer, NULL);


    pthread_join(con, NULL);
    pthread_join(pro, NULL);


    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex); 
    pthread_cond_destroy(&condc); 
    pthread_cond_destroy(&condp); 
    sleep(sleepTime);

}
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: Ahh my mistake, the Expected output is for the numbers to increment starting from the 4 parameter taken in at the start  

   producer 12323112 produced 7   
    producer 12312310 produced 8   
    consumer 1321312 consumed 7  
   producer ...9   
    consumer ..... consumed 8`

Comment: As is, each (producer) thread starts with its own `item` variable, initialised to `START_NUMBER`.  Since they each use and increment their own local copy, you'll get as many copies of each number as you have producers... displayed twice each, once when produced and once when consumed -- so eight times for four producer threads.

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting, i am almost brand new to this site, basically what it would say is.... produced 7  newline produced 8 newline consumed 7 newline produced 9 newline consumed 8 newline..... and then loop infinitely

Comment: If you don't want the repeats, maybe the producers should use a global variable as a counter instead of their own local `item` variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help Dmitri, after moving around the lines you told me about and some discussion with one of my friends I finally got it to start outputting the right numbers!

[This is the output i have been looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN4Se.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
typedef int buffer_item;
#define BUFFER_SIZE 5
#define TRUE 1


buffer_item START_NUMBER;
buffer_item item; 
int counter;
int insert_item(buffer_item item);
int remove_item(buffer_item *item);  
buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
void* producer(void *ptr);
void* consumer(void *ptr);  
pthread_cond_t condc, condp;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int sleepTime, producerThreads, consumerThreads, a, item;
pthread_attr_t attr;
sem_t full, empty;

int insert_item(buffer_item item)
{
   if(counter < BUFFER_SIZE) {
      buffer[counter] = item;
      counter++;
      return 0;
   }
   else { 
      return -1;
   }
}
int remove_item(buffer_item *item)
{
   if(counter > 0) {
      *item = buffer[(counter-1)];
      printf("consumer%u consumed %d\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self(),buffer[counter-1]);
      counter--;
      return 0;
   }
   else { 
      return -1;
   }
}

void* producer(void *ptr) {     
   while(TRUE) {
      sleep(sleepTime);     
      sem_wait(&empty);
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);    
      if(insert_item(START_NUMBER)) {
         fprintf(stderr, "error \n");
      }
      else {
        printf("producer%u produced %d\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self(),START_NUMBER);
        START_NUMBER++;
      }     
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      sem_post(&full);
  }
 }

void* consumer(void *ptr) {
   while(TRUE) {
      sleep(sleepTime);
      sem_wait(&full);
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      if(remove_item(&item)) {
         fprintf(stderr, "error \n");
      }
      else {
        // printf("consumer%u consumed %d\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self(),&START_NUMBER);
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      sem_post(&empty);

   }
}
void initializeData() {
   pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
   sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&empty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
   pthread_attr_init(&attr);
   counter = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    sleepTime = atoi(argv[1]);
    producerThreads = atoi(argv[2]);
    consumerThreads = atoi(argv[3]);
    START_NUMBER = atoi(argv[4]);
    item = START_NUMBER;
    initializeData();
    pthread_t pro, con;


    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&condc, NULL); 
    pthread_cond_init(&condp, NULL); 

   for(a=0; a< consumerThreads;a++)
    pthread_create(&con, NULL, consumer, NULL);
    for(a=0;a<producerThreads;a++)
    pthread_create(&pro, NULL, producer, NULL);


    pthread_join(con, NULL);
    pthread_join(pro, NULL);


    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex); 
    pthread_cond_destroy(&condc); 
    pthread_cond_destroy(&condp); 
    sleep(sleepTime);

}
```